# Way to persist process spawned by a task on an agent?

Tags: azure-devops, task, agent, azure-devops-extensions, azure-pipelines-task-lib

I'm developing an Azure Devops extension with tasks in it. In one of the tasks, I'm  starting a process and I'm doing configurations. In another task, I'm accessing the  same process API to consume it. This is working perfectly fine, but I notice that after the job is done, my process is killed. I was planning to allow the user to do the configuration on an agent and be able to access it in another job or pipeline.

Is there a way to persist a process on an agent? I feel like the agent is killing every child processes created on cleanup. Where can I find documentation on this?

**Edit**: I managed to find this [thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/497786/release-pipeline-killed-my-node-server-process-in.html) that talks about a certain `Process.clean` variable but there's not any more information about it and I didn't find documentation on it.

Answer (score 1):

Your feeling is correct. Agents clean up spawned processes when the job finishes, and that's by design. A single machine can have multiple agents on it, and multiple agents can be running tasks in parallel. What if you have one machine with 10 agents on it, and they all start up this process at once?

IMO, the approach you're taking is suspect. If you need to persist information across jobs, there are numerous ways to do so (for example, an output variable containing JSON) that don't involve spawning a service that continues running outside the scope of the job that started it.

Comment: You might be right about the approach, but I still think it's possible to skip it. I found an interesting thread talking about it, see my edited question.